# Nonstationary (but not I(1)) components in VAR model. What should I do?

Tags: vector-autoregression, stationarity

I have several time-series, which are non-stationary, but it looks like they have a number of structural breaks, resulting in different trend coefficients. I need to estimate a VAR model and make variance decomposition. But if I estimate it in levels, VAR seems to be non-stationary as well (eigenvalues are all less then one, but some of them are really close). As I understand it, differencing the data is not correct here, because my time-series are not I(1). But what should I do? I think that I should estimate the structural breaks, "clean" my data from them and make a stationary series. But these breaks are not uniform for all series, some of them have different timing and power, although the nature of data allows to think, that some of this breaks may be caused by the same exogenous shocks, so they are related. So I am afraid, that I will lose some of important information about dynamics of series.